# How to remove class if the height of relative element is bigger then window scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here is the link](http://bzm.me/sozdanie-prodayuschih-saytov-ot-a-do-ya.html) to page I'm trying to make work as needed in question. Scroll down the green block. The left side of tab block will stick to the top of the screen. So the question is how to remove class "sticked" when this left side reaches the end of parent element?

```
var distance = $('.forlabels').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
       $('.forlabels').addClass('sticked')
    }
  else {
       $('.forlabels').removeClass('sticked')
   } 

  if ($window.scrollTop() >= $('.forlabels').parent().outerHeight())  {
       $('.forlabels').removeClass('sticked')
    }  

});
```

and html part:

```
<div class="fbox">
    <div class="forlabels-section">
    <div class="forlabels">  

      <label for="sect-1" class="tab--element sect-1 tab--checked">+ Интернет-магазин</label>

      <label for="sect-2" class="tab--element sect-2">+ SEO-лендинги</label>

      <label for="sect-3" class="tab--element sect-3">+ Контент-маркетинг</label>

      <label for="sect-4" class="tab--element sect-4">+ Реклама и SEO</label>

      <label for="sect-5" class="tab--element sect-5">+ СуперКонверсия</label>

      <label for="sect-6" class="tab--element sect-6">+ Эксклюзивный дизайн</label>

      <label for="sect-7" class="tab--element sect-7">+ СуперАналитика</label>

</div><!--forlabels-->
 </div><!--forlabels-section-->
  </div><!--fbox-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to calculate the bottom position of the wrapper and check if the bottom of the labels extends beyond that point - if so, change the positioning to `absolute` with `bottom:0px;` so it's attached to the bottom of the wrapper.

Now that it's `position: absolute`, you'll need to add a check to see if the screen has gone past the top of the labels again and if so, switch back to `fixed`.

All in all there's four comparisons to make and three possible outcomes. This code is pretty well documented to explain:

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  var labels = $('.forlabels'),
      labelsSec = $('.forlabels-section'),

      bottomOfLabels = labels.outerHeight() + labels.offset().top,
      bottomOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.outerHeight() + labelsSec.offset().top,
      topOfLabels = labels.offset().top,
      topOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.offset().top,

      isAboveTopSec = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabelsSec,
      isAboveTop = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabels,
      isBelowTop = $window.scrollTop() >= topOfLabels,
      isBelowBottom = bottomOfLabelsSec <= bottomOfLabels;


  if ( !isAboveTopSec && ((isBelowTop && !isBelowBottom) || isAboveTop)) {
    //  Window is not above the wrapper
    //  Window is past the top of the wrapper, but not past the bottom
    //  Or, the window is above the labels (scrolling up after sticked2)
    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked')
      .removeClass("sticked2");
  } else if (isBelowBottom) {
    //  Window is past the bottom of the wrapper
    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked2')
      .removeClass('sticked');
  } else {
    //  Window is above the wrapper
    $('.forlabels')
      .removeClass('sticked sticked2');
  }
});
```

The relevant CSS

```
.forlabels-section {
  position: relative;
}
.sticked{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: inherit;
}
.sticked2{
  bottom:0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/bebq6fb1/1/

Comment: Excelent solution. Will try to understand it and attach it to my goal! Thanks alot!